# Newest FBConnect with Objective-C Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fbconnect

I am using newest SDK for facebook for iphone application. My Problem is that i could not maintain the session through out the application. everytime i have to make new facebook variable and initilize it to app id to work. But that leads to multiple session And the if i am logged in even then it show "LOGIN" in the next tab. Here is scenario

1) Home Tab, i logged in

2) Second Tab, the button for facebook shows that i am not login, I have to relogin.

and so on with the third tab.

Is there a way that i keep one session in all the application?

Can you please guide me in this problem

```
[_facebook isSessionValid];
```

it returns me that the Session is not valid, Can you please help me out in this regard.
Please guide me.

```
permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream",@"read_mailbox", @"offline_access",@"read_friendlists", @"friends_location", @"friends_birthday",@"friends_about_me",@"friends_hometown",@"friends_relationships",@"friends_relationship_details",nil] retain];
```

facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:appId];
 [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

I put this code in App delegate, and assigned it into new view controller like this

```
fb = [[Facebook alloc] init];
fb = appdel.facebook;
```

But it says Try again, error occured (corrected)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a new facebook variable with every page. You need to have a global one stored in a place that's accessible by the different views/classes. You can do this easily by having the facebook variable be stored in the app delegate. The classes can reference this facebook object like so:

`((YourAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).facebook`

(assuming that you have a property called `facebook` in your app delegate)

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1 thing, please, do i need to do as below ? fb = [[facebook alloc]  init];      fb = appdel.facebook;

Comment: I'm not sure where you assigned it into your new view controller. You can either assign it to your view controller or, from your view controller, access the app delegate's variable like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with FBConnect for a good few days and did not find the documentation at github.com was helping me. Each time I tried to upload a test photo from my iPad app to my Facebook page I got an error_code=101 Invalid API Key.

I fixed this by following the very clear instructions at:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

which takes you step by step through the process.